# Generate a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop for my code. The idea is not to use so many "for" loops to put it into a function

```py
int_list = [[[1]],2,[[[[3]]]]]

for i in int_list:
    if type(i) != list:
        list_of_lists.append(i)
    else:
        for a in i:
            if type(a) != list:
                list_of_lists.append(a)
            else:
                for j in a:
                    if type(j) != list:
                        list_of_lists.append(j)
                    else:
                        for h in j:
                            if type(h) != list:
                                list_of_lists.append(h)
                            else:
                                for r in h:
                                    if type(r) != list:
                                        list_of_lists.append(r)
```

Expected Output

`list_of_lists = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reduce **for loop is to create a recursive function**.

The function recursively calls itself on that `sublist(i)` by passing it as an argument to `helper()`. The resulting list is then extended to the result list using the `extend()` method.

If it's `instance` is not a `list`. it runs else part. **appending value** into the `lis`

**Code:**

```
def helper(lis):
    res=[]
    for i in lis:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            res.extend(helper(i))
        else:
            res.append(i)
    return res

int_list=[[[1]], 2, [[[[3]]]]]
list_of_lists=helper(int_list)
print(list_of_lists)
```

**Output:**

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is the ideal way to flatten a list like this.  If you really want to do it in a single while loop, though, it is possible, by creating a stack to help you keep track of where you are in each sublist.

This happens automatically for you when you define and call a recursive function; every call to the function puts all the function's local variables onto a "stack", just like the code below puts the current list and index onto a list called `stack` every time a new sublist is discovered.

```
int_list = [[[1]],2,[[[[3]]]]]

flat_list = []
stack = []
i = 0
while True:
    if i >= len(int_list):
        # We're at the end of this sublist,
        # so go back to the stack to pick up where we left off.
        if not stack:
            break  # all done!
        int_list, i = stack.pop()
    elif isinstance(int_list[i], list):
        # Keep track of the current list and the next item
        # for us to look at, and then start looking at this sublist.
        stack.append((int_list, i+1))
        int_list, i = int_list[i], 0
    else:
        # We found a scalar item!  Add it to the flat list.
        flat_list.append(int_list[i])
        i += 1

assert flat_list == [1, 2, 3]
```